# Increase font size in llncs, including in headings and abstract

Tags: fontsize, lncs

I'd like to increase the font size in the llncs class (it defaults to 10pt) now available on recent [CTAN](https://ctan.org/pkg/llncs). However, just doing `\documentclass[11pt]{llncs}` does not increase the size of the font in the abstract or in the title, making it quite odd compared to the article class:

`llncs` documentclass:

[image]

Compare to the `article` documentclass:

[image]

MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{llncs}
\title{The size of the title seems to be ok}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\begin{abstract}
  But the abstract has really tiny font font.
\end{abstract}

Compare to the main body font.

\section{Similarly text in section heading is quite small}

Compared to a usual section in article.

\end{document}
```

Comment: Why you use `llncs`? I suppose, that this is required from you. With other words, it is expected, that you obey document design determined by this document class and not change any settings ...

Comment: the class uses footnotesize in the abstract (more precisely that use \small but redefine \small to be \footnotesize.

Comment: @Zarko I need `llncs` for the published version, but I want to change the layout for the online arxiv version without rewriting everything (including the institutions, theorem numbering…) for another class.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Good point. How could I redefine `\small` to be… `\small`? Also, any trick to make it change the size of the section title appropriately?

Comment: I tried to use `\renewcommand\small{\fontsize{10pt}{12pt}\selectfont}` it seems to work for the abstract, but I'm not sure if it's the recommended way to proceed. But I don't know what to do for the section title.